# Защита аудио наложением войстега в HTML5

Tags: плеер, аудио

**Скажите. Как сделать чтобы при включении Mp3, поверх включался еще один файл voiceteg и повторялся с интервалами пока работает Mp3???**

Кстати на базе плеера [Flabell29-Mp3-Player-for-Adobe-Flash](http://www.flabell.com/flash/Mp3-Player-for-Adobe-Flash-29), ну очень надо для продажи собственной музыки.

Зарание всем спасибо!!!!

Comment: Это никак не защитит аудиофайлы, потому что их можно будет стянуть напрямую.

Comment: То есть файлы которые лежат допустим здесь http://www.myflashstore.net/profile/49623tunesgoboom можно просто стянуть? Какой тогда смысл? У кого нибудь есть еще мысли реалезации данного вопроса???

Comment: если оно звучит в наушниках, значит можно утянуть. Другое дело, что обычно в паблик выкладывают либо сильно короткие куски, либо сильно искаженные (на указанном сайте они как раз сильно искаженные).

Comment: Как оно может быть сильно искаженное, если я сам туда заливал битрейт 320кб\с. Их тег накладывается автоматом, а при покупке автоматом отправляет чистый файл!

Comment: наложжить две дороги на клиенте и на сервере *с этой точки зрения* - принципиально разные вещи

Comment: Вот мне и надо на сервере. Заливаю чистый,воспроизводится с тегами.

Comment: Для этого на сервере делается обработка файла, например, с помощью ffmpeg/libav. Клиенту слушать отдается модифицированный файл, при покупке отдается оригинальный.

Comment: О а по подробней. Или ссылку если возможно.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19231722/voice-tagging-audio-using-ffmpeg-overlay